# How far back through history should one delve into to be in a position to understand present day affairs

Tags: history

At the age of 20, I have decided that with the current state of the world, I can no longer afford to be in the dark, in light of current events.

I decided not to delve straight into messy, chaotic present of our times, but to delve into it's history; the seeds with which were planted by others left behind.

However, having said that, I am hardly going to, say, look into our descent out of Africa, as whilst interesting, is probably going a bit too far.

In specific, what is of great concern is the recent conflict we seem to witnessing in the world, other things that are politically related, say, matters of economics, aren't of great concern, at least in retrospect.

The question is then, is *how* for back, should one glance into history, to understand the present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should study depends on which issues are important to you.  Each issue involves different groups of people.  These groups of people remember (with varying degrees of distortion) certain actions by other groups of people involved in these issues.  These groups of people also (more-or-less) follow doctrines, which were shaped by historical people and events.  You should look into the historical events that these groups of people remember, and that influenced their doctrines.

In today's news, some key issues are:

- Organized group(s) of Muslims are launching guerrilla wars against France and Russia.
- France has cradle-to-grave socialism.
- Russia used to have cradle-to-grave communism.
- France and Russia were historically Christian nations, whose major sects [excommunicated](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/13535a.htm) each [other](http://orthodoxinfo.com/general/greatschism.aspx) in 1054 A.D.
- France, Russia, China, and the United States are currently *de facto* empires.
- There are two major groups of Muslims.  At various times, each has ruled large empires.  These empires conquered, desertified, and/or assimilated large nations of previously Christian, Jewish, or pagan peoples.

If you want to study these issues, you might want to research:

- Abraham's exile from Mesopotamia.  Judaism, Christianity, and Islam all trace their roots back through Abraham.
- The Hebrew conquest of Canaan.  This conquest has been a template for religiously inspired wars of conquest with the intent to settle.
- The lives of Saul, David, and Solomon.
- The lives of John the Baptist, Jesus, Peter, and Paul.
- The [effects](https://hbdchick.wordpress.com/2014/03/10/big-summary-post-on-the-hajnal-line/) of the western Christian church's discouragement of inbreeding, starting circa 450 A.D.
- The life of Mohammed, including the wars he started, and the laws and traditions he established and/or honored.
- The split between Sunni and Shia, which happened within a generation of Mohammed's death.
- The [effects](http://www.unz.com/article/cousin-marriage-conundrum/) of Islam's encouragement of inbreeding.
- The fact that Mohammed's wars inadvertently triggered a Dark Age in Western Europe, and the process by which Europe recovered from that Dark Age.
- The Mediterranean and Eastern European slave trades:  Who captured whom?  Who were the slave dealers?
- How (and why) the Industrial Revolution happened in Europe.
- Why, once Europeans started building steam engines, they were able to [easily](https://web.archive.org/web/20141106022217/http://www.everyjoe.com/2014/09/01/politics/why-arab-armies-bad-worthless/) conquer most Muslim societies.
- The goals of socialism and anti-clericalism in 19th-Century Europe.
- Communism's prophecy that capitalism is unsustainable.
- How World Wars I and II cut the hearts out of Europe's empires.
- How socialism's success has caused a [demographic time-bomb](http://www.tomkratman.com/Rantcaliphate.html) for Europe, and how Europe's leaders hope that immigration can delay economic implosion.
- How guerrilla wars were fought in Iberia during the Napoleonic wars, in the Hejaz during World War I, in China during 1926-1949, in Cuba during 1956-1959, and in Iraq during 2003-2008.  These particular wars have inspired current guerrillas, and the conventional and special forces that oppose guerrillas.

A few books that cover most of these topics:

- *The Bible.*  (Also get a good concordance.)
- *The Koran.*
- *[Medieval Cities](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691162395).*
- *[The Communist Manifesto](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1848/communist-manifesto/).*
- *[A History of Warfare](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0679730826).*
- *[The Road to Serfdom](http://www.barefootsworld.net/serfdom.html).*
- *[Guerrilla Warfare](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0803270755)*, by Che Guevara.

For a terrifying illustration of the lingering psychological effects of the World Wars, you can watch Pink Floyd's *[The Wall](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0006ZE7G2)*, Spielberg's *[Schindler's List](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B0U2SFE)*, or Spielberg's *[Saving Private Ryan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00001ZWUS)*.

If you want to understand the difference between the traditional American "go out and invent/build/settle the wilderness" minimal government approach and the European government-centric approach, read the Phillips Bradley translation of *[Democracy in America](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0679728252)*.  Joel Millman's *[The Other Americans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0140242171)* presents best-case scenarios for immigration to the United States.

*[Dune](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0441172717)* is a science fiction story, with themes based on the potential advantages of a Sunni desert society that has been religiously inspired to work toward a common goal.  It is set in a far future with space travel, psychohistory, poisons, knife-fighting, and no computers.

Comment: Jasper I don't know how to thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for, that being, past/current events that are tied into the conflict we are seeing into today's world, with what's going on with ISIS/Syria/Libya/everything else. I probably should've been more specific, though am glad you caught on to it. I'll be sure to look through most of not everything that you have recommended. Thanks again my friend :)

Comment: Mostly excellent answer. I must point out that much of biblical references **matter** in terms of shaping modern views and thus events, but are NOT considered proven historical events by professional historians.

Comment: To be honest, I would also suggest padding even further back, and add readings on Rome, Greece, Medes/Persian empire, or even Assyrians. A lot of that stuff matters.

Comment: Mmm, seems a bit time consuming to go that far back, wouldn't say, the 1700's - present day be sufficient, this would cover the french and american revolution, both world wars, womens/gay/black right (I just realised how messed up we used to be), and the rise of modern terrorism.

Comment: When you want to paint a complete picture of the history between Christianity and Islam, you should definitely add the crusades.

Comment: @Philipp, Fortunately, *A History of Warfare* has several long passages on the Crusades.  Unfortunately, I do not own a good book-length discussion of the Crusades.

Comment: This answer is built on the (interesting) idea that the modern World can/must be understood essentially through the prism of religions. I believe this is extremely misleading.

Comment: Meanwhile, you have many facts plain wrong ("*France has cradle-to-grave socialism."* - What ??) and your program would miss many, many key features of the modern world (e.g. India, China, Japan, Environment, Technology, Nationalism, Culture,...)

Comment: @Evargalo -- As explained in the answer, the history you should study depends on the issues you want to understand.  This answer focuses on the issues in the "key issues" paragraph.  Those issues were a nascent religious war against a democratic socialist state (France) and a former communist state (Russia).  Thus, the emphasis on religion, and the focus on Western Europe, Eastern Europe, and the Muslim world.  If you are interested in different issues, you will want to look into different historical events to understand their context.